# how to get string data from the column of the data table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

hi i am trying to convert &#x0A into &#x0D&#x0A in select query

```
SELECT TOP 1  
 @F0 = ID,  
 @F1 = MessageSource,  
 @F2 = MessageID,  
 @F3 = MessageText  
FROM [dbo].[sample_MESSAGE]  
WHERE MessageStatus = 'FR' and MessageSource=@Param1   -- VALID  --Lavanya

SELECT @F0 AS F0, @F1 AS F1, @F2 AS F2, replace(@F3,'&#x0A;','&#x0D;&#x0A;') AS F3  
FOR XML RAW
```

but it was  not replacing the  values which i was assigned, can any one suggest me on this

Comment: You're not closing the parens on `REPLACE`. That should be issuing a syntax error.

Comment: sry for the trouble, i have edited see my question, check it now,i hope it was not targeting the data of the messagetext column

Comment: Do you want to search and replace the string &#x0A or the value ? Because if your looking to replace the value, right now your searching the string...

Comment: Are you expecting it to replace the strings as shown, or to perform some conversion of hexadecimal values to control characters, e.g. carriage return and line feed?

Comment: Maybe its because you try to replace the value `&#x0A`, but you are searching `&#x0A;`, you know, with an extra semicolon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you mean this:

```
  … REPLACE(@F3, CHAR(10), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)) AS F3 …
```

or this:

```
  … REPLACE(@F3, NCHAR(10), NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10)) AS F3 …
```

depending on whether `@F3` is `varchar` or `nvarchar`.

Answer (score 0):

It works:

```
DECLARE @F0 INT, @F2 INT, @F1 INT, @F3 VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT 
 @F0 = 1,  
 @F1 = 2,  
 @F2 = 3,  
 @F3 = '&#x0A;'  


SELECT @F0 AS F0, @F1 AS F1, @F2 AS F2, replace(@F3,'&#x0A;','&#x0D;&#x0A;') AS F3  
FOR XML RAW
```

**so**

you have to find out what is bad in your text data. If text contains chars with codes 10 - you should not to make `REPLACE` to find string like this `'&#x0A;'`  replace `CHAR(10)` to `CHAR(10)_CHAR(13)` instead